# How do I Autofill a cell with string depending if it's in another list?

Tags: excel, vba, vlookup

I'm trying to create a sheet where I can type one text value in and it autofills with the closest possible match from another list of strings.

I've tried using the VLOOKUP function in VBA, with 4th argument set to TRUE to look for a partial match. I've also tried using the VLOOKUP function in excel only and not VBA. The result is half of what I want, let's say I enter "cookie" in the cell, the function returns "Cleaning Supplies" since they both start with a C. Ideally, I'd want it to return Chocolate Cookie or something similar to that.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim KeyCells As Range

    Set KeyCells = Range("A:A")

If Not Application.Intersect(KeyCells, Range(Target.Address)) _
           Is Nothing Then

           Target.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Target.Value, Worksheets("StorageLocations").Range("A:A"), 1, True)

End If
End Sub
```

[image: example data]

The code works partially, coming back with a run-time error `Method 'Range' of object_ '_Worksheet' failed`. It also only comes back with the cleaning supplies comment from earlier.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You can use `Range.Find` to get the results like `Chocolate Cookie` when cell have value `Cookie`. Other than that without looking at the Data, it's impossible to find a Logic.

Comment: And you code is not complete, Is it a Selection change or Change event ?

Comment: Apologies. I corrected the syntax and added some example data.

Comment: Please read tag descriptions before adding them. The [tag:excel-vba] description specifically says **THIS TAG IS PENDING REMOVAL** in ALL CAPS as it's opening sentence, which means it should not be added to new posts. I've removed it for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try:**

- In Worksheet event paste

---

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Call fnd(Target)


End Sub
```

---

- In a New Module Paste

---

```
Sub fnd(rng As Range)

Application.EnableEvents = False

If rng.Column = 1 Then

    If Not Worksheets("StorageLocations").Range("A:A").Find(rng) Is Nothing Then

        rng.Value = Worksheets("StorageLocations").Range("A:A").Find(rng.Text).Value

    End If

End If

Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

**Explanation:**

- We need this `Enable Events` to change the value in Sheet, otherwise while changing the cell value it will keep firing the Change Event.
- It will always give you the First available Match in the Column

**Demo:**

[image]

Comment: Perfect! Thank you for the explanation as well. I think I understand, I basically created a loop that kept firing the change event since after I changed the cell myself it would change once again?

Comment: Yep .. Almost There :)